# copy string multiple times

Tags: c, arrays, string, copy

I am trying to copy and user imputed string multiple times using c code. Im new to coding.

```
 char toCopy[81];
 int numCopies;
 int i;

 printf("Enter string: ");
 scanf("%s",toCopy);

 printf("Enter number of copies: ");
 scanf("%r", numCopies);

 printf("%s * %r")

 puts("End");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `for` (or other loop) to perform multiplication of output. Moreover, consider changing your `printf` and `scanf` to have correct program behavior.

For example:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char toCopy[81];
    int numCopies;
    int i;

    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf("%80s",toCopy);  // 80 is a limit of string length

    printf("Enter number of copies: ");
    scanf("%d", &numCopies);  // send address of numCopies to scanf

    for(i = 0; i < numCopies; i++)   // loop for multiplication
    {
        printf("%s ", toCopy);   // correct string output
    }
    puts("\nEnd");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you explain more on this? so i need a loop to multiply? what is this called and where can i find information on copying a string?

Comment: For case if you want not output a string `numCopies` times, but create in memory new string with repetition of original string, read about the following function: `malloc` (to allocate memory for new string), `strcopy` (to copy content of one string to onother) and `strcat` (to concatenate strings)

Comment: must be a bug with the eclipse compiler i got it to work, just 1 more question how do i get it to out put it without spaces in between the words.

Comment: i want it to be TreeTreeTreeTree and not Tree Tree Tree Tree

Comment: If you do not need space, edit `printf("%s ", toCopy);` and delete space after `%s` to have `printf("%s", toCopy);`

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1:**

`scanf("%r", numCopies);`

is invalid.

you need to have something like

```
scanf("%d", &numCopies);
```

As per the `C11` standard document, chapter 7.21.6.2, `fscanf()` definition,

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.

**Problem 2**

`printf("%s * %r")`

also invalid. You need to supply the arguments to the format specifier mentioned in `printf()`. Also keep in mind, the format string supplied to `printf()` is for printning, not for evaluation of itself.

*Solution:*

You need to have [loops](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_loops.htm) in your code to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks looking into it now!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a for loop :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
int numCopy;
scanf("%d",&numCopy);
char strings[50];
scanf("%s",strings);//Or use gets(strings);
int i;// If you aren't using C99.
   for(i = 0;i<numCopy;i++) {
      printf("%s\n",strings);
   }
   return 0;
}
```